# display images in select option for selection -Django Python

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a PRoject and I am stuck on order page.

Here, I want to display list of product images in options tag so that a user can select one image from all or can upload an image functionality of uploading image is working correctly but the selection is not working.

- I want to show images to user so that user can select one of them.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    prod_ID = models.AutoField("Product ID", primary_key=True)
    prod_Name = models.CharField("Product Name", max_length=30, null=False)
    prod_Desc = models.CharField("Product Description", max_length=2000, null=False)
    prod_Price = models.IntegerField("Product Price/Piece", default=0.00)
    prod_img = models.ImageField("Product Image", null=True)

class ImageTemplate(models.Model):
    temp_id = models.AutoField("Template ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    temp_img = models.ImageField("Template Image", null=False)

class ImageTemplateProductMapping(models.Model):
    imageTemp_p_map_id = models.AutoField("Template Image & Product Map ID", primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    temp_id = models.ForeignKey(ImageTemplate, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name="Image Template ID")
    prod_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Product Id")
```

**views.py**

```
def order(request, id):
    products = Product.objects.all()

    ImageTemplateProductsList = []
    
    try:
        ImageTemplateProductsMap = ImageTemplateProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
        ImageTemplateProductsList = [data.temp_id.temp_img for data in
                                     ImageTemplateProductsMap]
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    context = {'products': products,
               "ImageTemplateProductsList": ImageTemplateProductsList
               }

    return render(request, 'user/order.html', context)
```

**order.html**

```
{% extends 'user/layout/userMaster.html' %}
{% block title %}Order{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
form
{
position:relative;
}
.tasksInput
{
margin-right:150px;
}
label
{
vertical-align: top;
}

{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row rounded mx-auto d-block d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 mr-1">Custom</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 ml-1">Package</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card border border-secondary">
                    <div class="card body mx-2 mt-4 mb-2">
                        {% for product in products %}
                        <a id="{{ product.prod_ID }}" class="card-header" style="font-size:5vw;color:black;"
                           href="{% url 'user-order' product.prod_ID  %}">
                            <h5 class="h5">{{ product.prod_ID }}. {{ product.prod_Name }}</h5></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <form>
                    <div class="card mx-2 my-2 border border-secondary">
                        <div class="my-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group row mx-2">
                                    <label for="quantity"
                                           class="form-control-label font-weight-bold card-header col-4 ml-4 my-auto"
                                           style="background-color:#e3e4e6"><h5>Quantity : </h5></label>
                                    <input id="quantity" class="form-control col-5 mx-2 my-auto" type="number">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group row mx-2">
                                    <label for="ImageTemplateProductsList"
                                           class="form-control-label font-weight-bold card-header col-4 ml-4"
                                           style="background-color:#e3e4e6"><h5>Image Template : </h5></label>
                                    <div id="ImageTemplateProductsList" class="mx-2">
                                        <input id="Upload" type="radio" name="ImageSelection" value="Upload"/> Upload an
                                        Image
                                        <input type="file" name="file" class='btn btn-outline-secondary type my-2'>
                                        <br>
                                        <input id="Select" type="radio" name="ImageSelection" value="Select"/> Select
                                        From Templates
                                        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                                        <input type="button" name="url" style='display: none;'
                                               class='btn btn-outline-secondary type my-2'
                                               value="Choose Template" data-toggle="modal"
                                               data-target="#exampleModalLong">

                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                             aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Select
                                                            Template</h5>
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                                aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="d-flex-row justify-content-center modal-body"
                                                         style="background:red;">
                                                        <div>

<!-- Here I want to display images in select tag to make selection of one from all images but not able to achieve it. -->

                                                            <select id="ImageTemplateProductsList1">
                                                                {% for IT in ImageTemplateProductsList %}
                                                                <option value="{{IT}}"
                                                                ><img src="{{IT.url}}" height="250" width="400"
                                                                      class="border border-secondary rounded my-2 mx-3">
                                                                </option>
                                                                <br>
                                                                {% endfor %}
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger"
                                                                    data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
                                                                Select
                                                            </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row rounded mx-auto d-block d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success my-2">Place Order</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".type").hide();
$("input:radio").change(function() {
$(".type").hide();
$(this).next("input").show();
});
});
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('order/<int:id>', views.order, name="user-order"),
```

Comment: Select tags can't have images in them like that normally, check this question [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: I didn't find it very much helpful, can you please explain it with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly modified my html template with jquery and changed views a little bit and now it is working for me.

**order.html**

```
{% extends 'user/layout/userMaster.html' %}
{% block title %}Order{% endblock %}

{% block css %}
.t {
display: none;
}

img:hover {
opacity:0.8;
cursor: pointer;
}

img:active {
opacity:0.5;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
border: 20px solid rgb(228, 207, 94);
}

#dropdown{
height: 50px;
width: 50%;
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="row rounded mx-auto d-block d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 mr-1">Custom</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 ml-1">Package</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card border border-secondary">
                    <div class="card body mx-2 mt-4 mb-2">
                        {% for product in products %}
                        <a id="{{ product.prod_ID }}" class="card-header" style="font-size:5vw;color:black;"
                           href="{% url 'user-order' product.prod_ID  %}">
                            <h5 class="h5">{{ product.prod_ID }}. {{ product.prod_Name }}</h5></a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" id="templateValue" name="templateValue" value=""/>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                             <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-group row mx-2">
                                    <label for="ImageTemplateProductsList"
                                           class="form-control-label font-weight-bold card-header col-4 ml-4"
                                           style="background-color:#e3e4e6"><h5>Image Template : </h5></label>
                                    <div id="ImageTemplateProductsList" class="mx-2">
                                        <input id="Upload" type="radio" name="ImageSelection"
                                               class="templateSelection"/> Upload an
                                        Image
                                        <div class="type">
                                            <input type="file" name="image"
                                                   class='btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 SelectedImage'>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <input type="radio" id="Select" name="ImageSelection" class="templateSelection"
                                        /> Select
                                        From Templates
                                        <div class="type">
                                            {% for IT in ImageTemplateProductsList %}
                                            <input type="radio" name="image2" id="{{IT}}"
                                                   value="{{IT}}" class="SelectedImage t"/>
                                            <label for="{{IT}}">
                                                <img src="{{IT.url}}" style="width: 20vw;
                                                                             height: 20vw;
                                                                             padding: 2vw;"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <br>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row rounded mx-auto d-block d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success my-2">Place Order</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}

$("document").ready(function(){
$(".type").hide();
$("input:radio").on('change', function() {
$(".type").hide();
$(this).next("div").show();
});
$("#templateValue").val('');
$(".templateSelection").on('change', function(){
$("#templateValue").val('');
$("#templateValue").val($(this).attr('id'));
console.log($("#templateValue").val());
});
});


{% endblock %}
```

I have used hidden field to check whether user is trying to upload the image or select tha image and according to that I am taking the decision that what should I do:

**views.py**

```
def order(request, id):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    ImageTemplateProductsList = []

    try:
        ImageTemplateProductsMap = ImageTemplateProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
        ImageTemplateProductsList = [data.temp_id.temp_img for data in
                                     ImageTemplateProductsMap]
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if request.POST['templateValue'] == 'Upload':
                if 'image' in request.FILES:
                    Template_Value1 = request.FILES['image']

                    fs = FileSystemStorage()
                    fs.save(Template_Value1.name, Template_Value1)
                    TemplateValue = Template_Value1.name
            elif request.POST['templateValue'] == 'Select':
                TemplateValue = request.POST['image2']
            else:
                pass
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            pass
        order_store = Order(product_img=TemplateValue)

        order_store.save()
    context = {'products': products,
               "ImageTemplateProductsList": ImageTemplateProductsList
               }
    return render(request, 'user/order.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

def order(request, id):
products = Product.objects.all()
ImageTemplateProductsList = []

```
try:
    ImageTemplateProductsMap = ImageTemplateProductMapping.objects.filter(prod_id=id)
    ImageTemplateProductsList = [data.temp_id.temp_img for data in
                                 ImageTemplateProductsMap]
except AttributeError:
    pass

if request.method == 'POST':
    try:
        if request.POST['templateValue'] == 'Upload':
            if 'image' in request.FILES:
                Template_Value1 = request.FILES['image']

                fs = FileSystemStorage()
                fs.save(Template_Value1.name, Template_Value1)
                TemplateValue = Template_Value1.name
        elif request.POST['templateValue'] == 'Select':
            TemplateValue = request.POST['image2']
        else:
            pass
    except MultiValueDictKeyError:
        pass
    order_store = Order(product_img=TemplateValue)

    order_store.save()
context = {'products': products,
           "ImageTemplateProductsList": ImageTemplateProductsList
           }
return render(request, 'user/order.html', context)
```