# How can I design interface to ask user to select an image from given images?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask user to select an image from the displayed images. How I can I do that? I want something as the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YW9k.png):

[image: picture]

I have tried the code:

```html
<div class="tab">Select an image:
  <select>
    <option value="11"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="12"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="13"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="14"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <br>
    <option value="21"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="22"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="23"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="24"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <br>
    <option value="31"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="32"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="33"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <option value="34"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
    </option>
    <br>
</div>
```

My output:

[image: here]

Comment: And what is not working with the given code?

Comment: My output is added.

Comment: use background-color as here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: Don't use `<select>` as it does not support images. It also doesn't support `<br>` children. Just use `<button>` elements or `<input type="image">` elements.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov I think you mean `background-image`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Yes, right. I got it wrong by accident.

Comment: Just add a `click` event listener to images to select them in memory

Comment: so what's suppose to happen after you select the image?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')
for (let i = 0;i<imgs.length;i++){
   imgs[i].addEventListener('click',displayme)
}


function displayme(e){ 
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = e.target.outerHTML  
}
```

```css
#container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   align-items:center;
}

.row{
   display:flex;
   }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
   <div class = 'row'>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
   </div>
   <div class = 'row'>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
   </div>
   <div class = 'row'>
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something like this : [select2](https://select2.org/)

As far as I know, It can't be done by HTML and CSS only. `background-image` only works on Firefox. Hence jQuery is required with **select2** which is designed to replace a standard `<select>` box that is displayed by the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <select id='id_select2_example' multiple="multiple" style='min-width:200px'>
   <option value="11" data-img_src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"></option>
   <option value="12" data-img_src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"></option>
   <option value="13" data-img_src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg"></option>
  </select>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js">
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id_select2_example").select2({
          templateResult: customTemplate
        });
      });
 
      function customTemplate (obj) {
        var data = $(obj.element).data();
        if (data && data['img_src']) { 
          let $img_src = data['img_src'];
          let $template = $("<div><img src=\"" + $img_src + "\" style=\"width:100%;height:150px;\"/></div>");
          return $template;
        }
      }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```