# Render image to a choice/char field in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I have a CharField in my model like this:

`simbol_oznaka = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES_SIMBOLI, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Simbol", max_length=512)`

with a choice tuple like this:

CHOICES_SIMBOLI=(
('', 'No Image'),
('media/simboli/2.png', 'Image 1'),).

I was wondering how can I render the image in the django admin change/add form, because I don't want the user to see the "Image 1" text but rather the image itself.

This is what it currently looks like: [image]

Use case: I want users to be able to choose only one image from a few that would be displayed in the drop down (not necessarily drop down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the image in a select menu, that's a bit tricky since an `<option>` cannot have an `<img>` inside it, and I'd suggest looking at this question to figure which type of solution you want to take for that: [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Since it sounds as though you don't necessarily want a drop down and there are only a few images, you could perhaps use a radio group instead.

One way you could do this with Django would be to subclass the `RadioSelect` widget and override the `option_template_name` class variable like this:

```python
from django import forms

class SimbolRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    option_template_name = 'myapp/forms/widgets/simbol_radio_option.html'
```

Then you'll need to create the template specified in the `option_template_name` class variable:

```html
{% load static %}
<label{% if widget.attrs.id %} for="{{ widget.attrs.id }}"{% endif %}>
    <input type="{{ widget.type }}"
           name="{{ widget.name }}"
           value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"
           {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
    {% if widget.value %}
        <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}">
    {% else %}
        {{ widget.label }}
    {% endif %}
</label>
```

I came up with this template mostly by looking at the `radio_option.html` and other templates in the django source code: https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets

Then you'll want to use it in your form (or create one if you don't have one already):

```python
from django import forms

class SimbolAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'simbol_oznaka': SimbolRadioSelect,
        }
```

Then you can use the form in your Admin class:

```python
from django.contrib import admin

class SimbolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SimbolAdminForm

admin.site.register(Simbol, SimbolAdmin)
```

Then you'll end up with this in the admin:

[image: Two radio inputs for the first option 'No Image' and the second option an image with some shapes]

Comment: Thank you Luke, that's exactly what I did. It wasn't  100% what I wanted it to be but with few modifications it turned out to be more than a decent workaround. I'll accept this answer because of that fact.