# Image won't display in select option (HTML)

Tags: html

for some reason my image won't display in my select option.

```
<select>
   <option><img src="img/pic1.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;margin-left:4px">Option 1</option>
   <option><img src="img/pic1.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;margin-left:4px">Option 2</option>
   <option><img src="img/pic1.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;margin-left:4px">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

(Code simplified to understand problem, however, there are no special CSS arguments etc. for the options)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: SO is not documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`<option>`’s specification does not permit the use of non-textual information in its definition. [MDN’s page for `<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) spells this out pretty clearly:

> **Permitted content**
>
> Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

Suffice to say that `<img>` elements for not meet this standard.

Answer (score 0):

The `<option>` element, and therefore the select, can only contain text, not images.