# How to add SVG image icon in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add some SVG image icons to my dropdown list, I tried a few different approaches but none of them seems to be working.

```css
appt-status option[value="0"] {
    background-image: url(../icons/not_confirmed-icon.svg);
}

.appt-status option[value="1"] {
    background-image: url(../icons/confirmed-icon.svg);
}

.appt-status option[value="2"] {
    background-image: url(../icons/reschedule-icon.svg);
}

.appt-status option[value="3"] {
    background-image: url(../icons/pending-icon.svg);
}
```

```html
 <select class="form-control appt-status" data-bind="value: selectedAppointmentStatus">
                <option class=" status-list" value="1" style="color: #3EA47B">Confirmed</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="2" style="color: #FF0000">Reschedule</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="3" style="color: #FFA927">Pending</option>
                <option class="status-list" value="0" style="color: #3EA47B">Not opted-in</option>
</select>
```

With the above code, in inspect window, I can see icons are being loaded but I cannot see them in the dropdown.

Below is the design mockup I would like to achieve

[image]

---

But the result I am getting
[image]

Comment: Review this previous SO answer. In short, it's not widely supported natively. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: @wouch I tried but I still do not see icons in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use a pseudo element to add the icons to your `status-list` class, something like this might work

```
.status-list:before {
    content: url('../icons/reschedule-icon.svg');
}
```

Comment: I tried but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly achieve it with the HTML alone. To display the images in the select `drop-down` we have to use JavaScript libraries or pure JavaScript. you can add an image in select options using the `select2` jQuery library.

https://select2.org/dropdow

Answer (score 0):

```
.fa {
   font-family: 'Lato', 'Font Awesome 5 Free', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
    font-weight: 900;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: #3a9c7d;

}

<div class="select-box">

  <select name="sample" id="sample" class="fa">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="fa fa-address-card" class="fa">&#xf2bb; address card</option>
    <option value="fa fa-bell" class="fa">&#xf0f3; bell</option>
    <option value="fa fa-bookmark" class="fa">&#xf02e; bookmark</option>
    <option value="fa fa-building" class="fa">&#xf1ad; building</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Demo link:- https://codepen.io/mstanka/pen/mdPBdMa