# Is there a way to display an image as a select element option using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, element

I am building a table for keeping track of various employee information. The status is specifying whether the employee is at home, at office, on trip, etc. I want to let the user pick this status using an icon. Originally I was using emojis like this:

[image: Original design]

We want to keep this kind of design, but we want to be able to design our own icons now. So, we cannot use emojis. Instead, I need to have the same kind of look and feel but the  element needs to have an image inside of it. I've looked around on stack overflow and it looks like every solution requires jQuery. I am not allowed to use jQuery so I am wondering if this is even possible.

The table of employee info is generated through a JavaScript function that receives data from an SQL table and then creates elements if they don't exist/updates existing elements. Here is the part of the function that creates the status cell. My original solution was to create an image element and then append it to the statOption element but this did not work.

```
  // create status cell
  const statCell = document.createElement("td");
  statCell.id = "status_"+data[i].id;
  const statInput = document.createElement("select");
  if (data[i].stat == 3) newRow.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: crimson');
  statInput.id = "stat_"+data[i].id;
  statInput.setAttribute('onchange', 'field_changed(event)');
  statInput.classList.add("status");
  // HERES MY ATTEMPTED SOLUTION
  const airplaneImg = document.createElement("img");
  airplaneImg.setAttribute('src', 'airplane.png'); // inside of the same directory
  airplaneImg.setAttribute('width', '40px');
  airplaneImg.setAttribute('height', 40px');
  airplaneImg.setAttribute('alt', 'airplane');
  for (var k = 0; k < emojis.size; k++) {
    const statOption = document.createElement("option");
    statOption.id = "option_"+k;
    statOption.setAttribute('value', k);
    statOption.innerHTML = emojis.get(k);
    statOption.title = emojiDescriptors.get(k);
    if (k == data[i].stat) {
      statOption.selected = true;
      statInput.title = emojiDescriptors.get(k);
    }
    statOption.appendChild(airplaneImg);
    statInput.appendChild(statOption);
  }
  statCell.appendChild(statInput);
  newRow.appendChild(statCell);
```

Of course, I would need to do this with 4 different images. Ill need to figure out a way to implement it, but I just wanted to see if this way would work at all.

So am I just completely unable to do this sort of thing or is there still hope?

Comment: Can't you just set a background-image on the select options ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list

Comment: you cant set background image

Comment: whats wrong with putting an image inside an option inside a select tag?

Comment: `we want to be able to design our own icons now.` why don't you create a font? This is not only an easy solution for your case, but it's also the advised way to provide icons

Comment: The short answer to the question is 'no' - there is very little styling you can do with the vanilla select/option HTML. See however https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select for some ideas on how to implement your own select 'look alike'.

Comment: @ezio - what's wrong with trying to put a background image on an option element is that it won't work. There is almost no styling that can be applied to an option element - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: @AHaworth you can put img tag inside option tag like this <option><img></option>, why this wont work?

Comment: @ezio it won't work because the only permitted content of an option element is text.