# Want to add a Product Detail Dropdown (That shows Product title, image and price) inside a contact form in shopify

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid, contact-form-7, dropdownbox

I am trying to add a select dropdown (That shows Product title, image and price) form field inside a contact form that enable user to select product and selected products show under the field. I am using this code but it only display 50 product and just showing product titles and product image path, not the actual image.

```
 <label for="ContactFormProductNameField">Products</label>
    <select id="ContactFormProductNameField" name="contact[Product]" required>
        <option selected disabled>Choose your product</option>
        <option value="Others - No product-related concerns">Others - No product-related concerns</option>
        {% for product in collections['all'].products %} 
             <option value="{{ product.title }}">{{ product.title}}{{ product.featured_image}}</option>
        {% endfor %}   
              
    </select>
```

Comment: Two questions in one 
1) why only 50 options are shown - not clear from provided info
2) why image is not shown - clear from provided info

Answer (score 0):

On the first question why displaying only 50 products:
This could because of some data restriction from Shopify.
Did you check that collections['all'].products in the current context has length more than 50?

On the second one "just showing product titles and product image path, not the actual image."
{{ product.featured_image}} is probably just the image path not 'actual' image.
Also  the HTML `<option>` tag can contain only text inside it.
It could not contain  tag which is your intention. For that you will need custom select implementation.

Check this thread [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)