# Adding image to select options does not work

Tags: css

I started from this link
[How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

and built my own example:

```css
select#language option[value="english"] {
  background-image: url('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1377/1377975.png');
}

select#language option[value="french"] {
  background-image: url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wikipedia/flags/256/FR-France-Flag-icon.png');
}
```

```html
<select id="language">
  <option>english</option>
  <option>french</option>
</select>
```

But I can't see the images in the options of the select dropdown box.

What am I doing wrong?
I would like to have the Flag displayed next to the language label.

P.S. I also have a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/marceltudor/pen/vYQoJKO) of the same above code.

Comment: Checking that SO link I just realized that it was only possible to do it in Firefox using this method that you are trying but currently it is not possible. I think JS/jQuery is necessary here. Do you want it using only CSS or you would accept a JS/jQuery solution ?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, without JS please.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to say is I don't think it is possible using CSS and can do it using JS/jQuery. So if you allowed JS/jQuery then I would have written an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible cross browsers. There are many javascript plugins out there that convert a select to divs with dropdowns and you can customize those using CSS.