# How to put a fontawesome icon <i> into a select option and stylize it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to put an icon into a select option and I am getting this error:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a child of `<option>`

I am putting asterisk icons into all my inputs to say that they are required just like this:

```
<label htmlFor="floatingInput31">
    {cli_nome !== '' ? null
    :<i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="icon-asterisco-obrigatorio"></i>
    }
    E-mail
</label>
```

Then I tried to put it in a select and got the error that I mentioned:

```
<select className="select-cidades" nome='cidades' id='cidade' value={end_cid_id} onChange={salvarCidade}>
    {end_cid_id === '' ? <option value='0000000'><i className="fa-solid fa-asterisk"> </i> Escolha a cidade</option> 
    :
    <option value="0000000">Escolha a cidade</option>
    }
    <option value="0000000">Escolha a cidade</option>
    {
        cidades.map((city) => {
            return <option key={city.cid_id} value={city.cid_id}>{city.cid_nome} - {city.cid_uf_sigla}</option>
        })
    }
</select>
```

I have already tried to put the icon code like `<option value='0000000'>&#xf069; Escolha a cidade</option>`, but this way I am not allowed to stylize it.

[image: All the inputs have red asterisks and i want to put this in a select]

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You're trying to do this in a React.js context right? You should add that to your question.

Comment: [Select options may not contain images or other markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list). You can [add Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41508095/1264804), though.

Comment: Could you explain what is the "mandatory option" in select? Do I understand correctly that you want to mark the *first value-less option* with a "fancy" asterisk, to denote user has to pick some *other* option from the same select?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: @myf Hello. Not really sure what you mean with "mandatory option" but the asterisk is in the "select title", i guess they are similar. I edited the question with and image in the and to show this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to put the asterisk (that means required) by changing the select to a bootstrap dropdown.

Here is the new syntaxe:

```
<div className='col-lg-8'>
                    <div className="dropdown mt-2" id="dropdown-cidades-area">
                        {cepFilled === true ? <button className="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="dropdown-menu-cidades" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" value={end_cid_id}>
                            {end_cid_nome}
                        </button>
                        : 
                        <>
                            {end_cid_id === ''? <button className="btn btn-secondary " type="button" id="dropdown-menu-cidades" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" value={end_cid_id}>
                                <i className="fa fa-solid fa-asterisk fa-2xs my-auto" style={{color: "#e41607"}} id="asterisk-cidades"></i> 
                                Escolha a cidade
                            </button>
                            :
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary " type="button" id="dropdown-menu-cidades" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" value={end_cid_id}>
                                {end_cid_nome}
                            </button>
                            }
                            
                        </>
                        }
                        
                        <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-menu-button">
                            {
                                cepFilled ?
                                cidades.map((city) => (
                                    // <a key={city.cid_id} className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={() => salvarCidade(city.cid_id)}>
                                    //     {city.cid_nome} - {city.cid_uf_sigla}
                                    // </a>
                                    <a key={city.cid_id} className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={() => salvarCidade(city.cid_id)}>
                                        {city.cid_nome} - {city.cid_uf_sigla}
                                    </a>

                                )) :
                                <>
                                    <a className="dropdown-item" onClick={() => salvarCidade} value={end_cid_id}> Escolha a cidade</a>
                                    {
                                        cidades.map((city) => (
                                            <a key={city.cid_id} className="dropdown-item" onClick={() => salvarCidade(city.cid_id)}>
                                                {city.cid_nome} - {city.cid_uf_sigla}
                                            </a>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).