# Dropdown select with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to create a dropdown select which has images instead of text as the options.  I've done some Googling and searching here on Stack Overflow, and the answer generally given is to use the [jQuery combobox](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).

The problem with this solution, it seems to me, is that you have to provide text.  It looks like the images are just icons that accompany that text on the left.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but this solution wouldn't cover what I'm trying to do-- which is completely replace the text with images.

Some background on what I'm trying to do-- I'm trying to create a dropdown for users to select line thickness on an online painting/doodling app.  The images would be lines of different thickness, kind of like mspaint.

Comment: Why not add the text and give it a styling of text-indent:-9999%; ?

Comment: Surely you could go for the classic `&nbsp;` as the text inside your items?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display images within a drop down box instead of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381679/how-to-display-images-within-a-drop-down-box-instead-of-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a images in select list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-a-images-in-select-list)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check this example .. everything has been done easily http://jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/

**EDIT**: Updated/working as of 2013, July 02: [jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/357](http://jsfiddle.net/GHzfD/357)

```
#webmenu{
    width:340px;
}

<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
    <option value="calendar" title="http://www.abe.co.nz/edit/image_cache/Hamach_300x60c0.JPG"></option>
    <option value="shopping_cart" title="http://www.nationaldirectory.com.au/sites/itchnomore/thumbs/screenshot2013-01-23at12.05.50pm_300_60.png"></option>
    <option value="cd" title="http://www.mitenterpriseforum.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/MIT_EF_logo_300x60.jpg"></option>
    <option value="email"  selected="selected" title="http://annualreport.tacomaartmuseum.org/sites/default/files/L_AnnualReport_300x60.png"></option>
    <option value="faq" title="http://fleetfootmarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Wichita-Apartment-Video-Tours-CTA60-300x50.png"></option>
    <option value="games" title="http://krishnapatrika.com/images/300x50/pellipandiri300-50.gif"></option>
</select>

$("body select").msDropDown();
```

Comment: Ashraf is using the msDropDown jQuery plugin. You can find more details here: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Comment: Ya i used the plugin mentioned in babonk question

Answer (score 52):

### You don't even need javascript to do this!

I hope this got you intrigued so here it goes. First, the html structure:

```
<div id="image-dropdown">
    <input type="radio" id="line1" name="line-style" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="line1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="line2" name="line-style" value="2" />
    <label for="line2"></label>
    ...
</div>
```

Whaaat? *Radio buttons?* Correct. We'll style them to look like a dropdown list with images, because that's what you're after! The trick is in knowing that when labels are correctly linked to inputs (that "for" attribute and target element id), the input will implicitly become active; click on a label = click on a radio button. Here comes comes slightly abbreviated css with comments inline:

```
#image-dropdown {
    /*style the "box" in its minimzed state*/
    border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:50px; overflow:hidden;
    /*animate the dropdown collapsing*/
    transition: height 0.1s;
}
#image-dropdown:hover {
    /*when expanded, the dropdown will get native means of scrolling*/
    height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;
    /*animate the dropdown expanding*/
    transition: height 0.5s;
}
#image-dropdown input {
    /*hide the nasty default radio buttons!*/
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;
}
#image-dropdown label {
    /*style the labels to look like dropdown options*/
    display:none; margin:2px; height:46px; opacity:0.2; 
    background:url("http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png") 50% 50%;}
#image-dropdown:hover label{
    /*this is how labels render in the "expanded" state.
     we want to see only the selected radio button in the collapsed menu,
     and all of them when expanded*/
    display:block;
}
#image-dropdown input:checked + label {
    /*tricky! labels immediately following a checked radio button
      (with our markup they are semantically related) should be fully opaque
      and visible even in the collapsed menu*/
    opacity:1 !important; display:block;
}
```

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/NDCSR/1/

NB1: you'll probably need to use it with **position:absolute** inside a container with position:relative +high z-index.

NB2: when adding more backgrounds for individual line styles, consider having the selectors based on the "for" attribute of the label like so:

```
label[for=linestyle2] {background-image:url(...);}
```

Comment: very clever.  +1 for sure.

Comment: Gee, this is creative :-) thx. ... but finally, one will probably end up wrapping some details into one's own JS frame. Which leads to finished JS frameworks...

Comment: I love this approach, and no JS needed :-)

Comment: This is nice answer. But I wonder, why you didn't used `.on("change","[name='line-style']")` instead setting time-interval for every 100ms to get checked item ?

Comment: Here's an improvement. I have a thing against ids, since they cant be put in a webcomponent, so i took out the label fors and instead put the radio buttons inside the label. Another problem is that since the radio button is positioned with top:0, everytime I select an item the select jumps back to the top, which is very annoying. I also wanted my dropdown to be able to have many items per row. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/NDCSR/623/

Comment: Very neat. Is there a reason why you don't use display:none to hide the radio buttons?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a straightforward html menu would be simpler. Use html5 data attributes for values or whatever method you want to store them and css to handle images as backgrounds or put them in the html itself.

Edit: If you are forced to convert from an existing select that you can't get rid of, there are some good plugins as well to modify a select to html. Wijmo and Chosen are a couple that come to mind

Answer (score 3):

If you think about it the concept behind a dropdown select it's pretty simple. For what you're trying to accomplish, a simple `<ul>` will do.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/></a> <!-- Selected -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt=""/></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You style it with css and then some simple jQuery will do. I haven't tried this tho:

```
$('#menu ul li').click(function(){
    var $a = $(this).find('a');
    $(this).parents('#menu').children('li a').replaceWith($a).
});
```

Answer (score 3):

PLAIN JAVASCRIPT:

DEMO: **http://codepen.io/tazotodua/pen/orhdp**

```js
var shownnn = "yes";
var dropd = document.getElementById("image-dropdown");

function showww() {
  dropd.style.height = "auto";
  dropd.style.overflow = "y-scroll";
}

function hideee() {
    dropd.style.height = "30px";
    dropd.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
  //dropd.addEventListener('mouseover', showOrHide, false);
  //dropd.addEventListener('click',showOrHide , false);


function myfuunc(imgParent) {
  hideee();
  var mainDIVV = document.getElementById("image-dropdown");
  imgParent.parentNode.removeChild(imgParent);
  mainDIVV.insertBefore(imgParent, mainDIVV.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```css
#image-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#image-dropdown {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*#image-dropdown:hover {} */

#image-dropdown .img_holder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#image-dropdown img.flagimgs {
  height: 30px;
}
#image-dropdown span.iTEXT {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<!-- not tested in mobiles -->


<div id="image-dropdown" onmouseleave="hideee();">
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs first" src="http://www.google.com/tv/images/socialyoutube.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">First</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/images/icons/fiabee.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Second</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="http://www.google.com/tv/images/lplay.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Third</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/images/icons/cloudprintlite.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Fourth</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is using ms-Dropdown : https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown

But data resource is json.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/tcibikci/w3rdhj4s/6

HTML

```
<div id="byjson"></div>
```

Script

```
<script>
        var jsonData = [
            {description:'Choos your payment gateway', value:'', text:'Payment Gateway'},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', description:'My life. My card...', value:'amex', text:'Amex'},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', description:'It pays to Discover...', value:'Discover', text:'Discover'},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', title:'For everything else...', description:'For everything else...', value:'Mastercard', text:'Mastercard'},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', description:'Sorry not available...', value:'cash', text:'Cash on devlivery', disabled:true},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', description:'All you need...', value:'Visa', text:'Visa'},
            {image:'https://via.placeholder.com/50', description:'Pay and get paid...', value:'Paypal', text:'Paypal'}
        ];
        $("#byjson").msDropDown({byJson:{data:jsonData, name:'payments2'}}).data("dd");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use combobox and add the following css `.ddTitleText{ display : none; }`

No more text, just images.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little to late on this, but you can do this using a simple bootstrap drop down and then do your code on select change event in any language or framework. (This is just a very basic solution, for other people like me who are just starting out and looking for a solution for a small simple project.)

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Select Image
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(../Content/Images/Backgrounds/background.png);height:100px;width:300px" class="img-thumbnail" href=""> </a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li> <a style="background-image: url(../Content/Images/Backgrounds/background.png);height:100px;width:300px" class="img-thumbnail" href=""> </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Years gone and such things is possible to create using pure javascript and css without jquery, here is an example: [Selectron23](https://selectron23.pluginus.net/)

Example:

```
let data1 = {
    options: [
        {
            value: 'usd',
            title: 'USD',
            text: 'United States Dollar',
            img: 'https://pluginus.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/united_states_of_america.gif'
        },
        {
            value: 'eur',
            title: 'EUR',
            text: 'European Euro',
            img: 'https://pluginus.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/european_union.gif'
        },
        {
            value: 'uah',
            title: 'UAH',
            text: 'Украинская гривна',
            img: 'https://pluginus.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/ukraine.gif'
        },
        {
            value: 'gbp',
            title: 'GBP',
            text: 'Great Britain pound',
            img: 'https://pluginus.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/united_kingdom.gif'
        }
    ],
    label: 'Select currency',
    selected: 'uah',
    width: '100%',
    imgpos: 'right',
    //name: 'my_value', //hidden input name
    fusion: false, //use if wrap  to fuse titles by keys with options description here
    max_open_height: 200, //max height (px) of opened drop-down when vertical scroll appears
};

var selector1 = new Selectron23(document.querySelector('#block-example'), data1);
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I tried several jquery based custom select with images, but none worked in responsive layouts. Finally i came across Bootstrap-Select. After some modifications i was able to produce this code.

[github repo link here](https://github.com/aslamswt/Responsive-Select-Dropdown-with-Images)

[image: github repo link here]