# Trying to create a drop-down navigation menu with images instead of text, need assistance linking

Tags: css, image, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I have been trying to find a way to have a drop down menu with images (not text) for my navigation and I seem to have found a solution but now my problem is adding a link to the images. I have done this all with CSS via this post:

[Dropdown select with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images#)

I am not very familiar with JavaScript, maybe it would be easier to do it that way but I finally got it to work somewhat with the above coding, I just can't figure out how to add links.

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Drop-down styling */   

image-dropdown {
/*style the "box" in its minimzed state*/
border:0px solid black; 
width:192px; 
height:80px; 
overflow:hidden;
/*animate the dropdown collapsing*/
transition: height 0.1s;
}

#image-dropdown:hover {
/*when expanded, the dropdown will get native means of scrolling*/
height:350px; 
overflow-y:visible;
/*animate the dropdown expanding*/
transition: height 0.5s;
z-index: 100;
display: block;
position: relative;
}

#image-dropdown input {
/*hide the nasty default radio buttons!*/
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
opacity:0;
}

#image-dropdown label[for=line1] {
/*style the labels to look like dropdown options*/
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:80px; 
opacity:0.2; 
background:url(nav_02.jpg);
z-index: 100;
}

label[for=line2]  {
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:50px; 
opacity:0.2;
background-image:url(subnav_02.jpg); 
z-index: 100;
} 

label[for=line3]   {
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:50px; 
opacity:0.2;
background-image:url(subnav_03.jpg);
z-index: 100;
}

label[for=line4]   {
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:50px; 
opacity:0.2;
background-image:url(subnav_06.jpg);  
}

label[for=line5]   {
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:50px; 
opacity:0.2;
background-image:url(subnav_08.jpg);
}

label[for=line6]   {
display:none; 
margin:2px; 
height:50px; 
opacity:0.2;
background-image:url(subnav_10.jpg);
}


#image-dropdown:hover label{
/*this is how labels render in the "expanded" state.
 we want to see only the selected radio button in the collapsed menu,
 and all of them when expanded*/
display:block;
opacity: 1; 
}

#image-dropdown input:checked + label {
/*tricky! labels immediately following a checked radio button
  (with our markup they are semantically related) should be fully opaque
  and visible even in the collapsed menu*/
opacity:1 !important; display:block;
}
```

and here is my html:

```
<div id="image-dropdown"><input checked="checked"
id="line1" name="line-style" value="1"
type="radio" /><label for="line1"></label>
<input id="line2" name="line-style" value="2"
type="radio" /><label for="line2"></label><input
id="line3" name="line-style" value="3"
type="radio" /><label for="line3"></label><input
id="line4" name="line-style" value="4"
type="radio" /><label for="line4"></label><input
id="line5" name="line-style" value="5"
type="radio" /><label for="line5"></label><input
id="line6" name="line-style" value="6"
type="radio" /><label for="line6"></label><input
id="line7" name="line-style" value="7"
type="radio" /><label for="line7"></label></div>
```

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated, I've been messing around with this for days...

Comment: Save yourself the confusion and trouble and build a true, tested, and reliable drop-down menu that takes either text, images or both - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this site](http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/) very useful when creating a purely CSS dropdown menu

Just replace the text with images