# Dropdown select with background images and w/o Javascript

Tags: html, css

using o.v's solution ("You don't even need javascript to do this!") from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images/9599581)

i am able to successfully get background images in a dropdown box.
however, it always appear under other html elements. 
see here [here](http://beton2.floxyk.co.il/he/water-based-concrete-stain-litre-detail)

changing the z-index doesn't help.

any suggestions ?

(sorry for the duplicate but my reputation doesn't allow me to post on that thread)

Comment: Your link isn't working

Comment: I can't really understand what background-image are you referring and where do you want it to be. Consider adding pictures of the wanted result.

Comment: talking about dropdown background colors for each text. read the thread i referred to. anyway, a solution was given by koala_dev. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed) so you just need to add this to your CSS:

```
#image-dropdown {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also it's bad practice to just use a large number for the z-index in an effort to bring it forward, in your case some of your links have `z-index:2` so setting the value to `3` for the dropdown will suffice