# Add html img tag in option text

Tags: html, forms

Is there any way to put img tag in the text of a html option?
For example i need something like this :

```
<select>
  <option value="1"> Text1<img src="foto.png"> </option>
  <option value="2"> Text2<img src="foto.png"> </option>
</select>
```

Comment: In title you want to add `<img>`, in description you want to add `<a>` and in example again you want to add `<img>`… o__0 btw, do you just want to show an image for visual effect..?

Comment: It isn't really possible with pure html...
With javascript it is, like in this topic: [Dropdown select with images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `option` cannot have any children elements, including `img`.

The [HTML5 `<option>` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-option-element) says the following *(Emphasis mine)*:

> If the first argument is not the empty string, the new object must have as its only child a Text node whose data is the value of that argument. Otherwise, **it must have no children**.

Comment: this link is dead
and using a child img tag doesn't work for me.

Comment: @khaverim The spec previously linked says that a child `img` does not work. I updated the link and added a quote.

Comment: the option tag is a member of the Night's Watch

Answer (score 0):

Only FireFox browser support Background images on Select options:

test.html

```
<select id="test_select">
  <option>test1</option>
  <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

style.css

```
select#test_select option[value="test1"]   { background-image:url(test1.png);   }
select#test_select option[value="test2"] { background-image:url(test2.png); }
```

Or you can use Jquery Selector to show Images.. http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/

Answer (score 0):

We can add a image inside option tag by jQuery and only in firefox!

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/L8s6spp4/1/

Html:

```
This code Only works in Firefox.
<br/>
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="_none"> - Select One - </option>
  <option value="asterisk">asterisk</option>
  <option value="plus">plus</option>
  <option value="euro">euro</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myselect option').each(function() {
      $(this).html('<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">' + $(this).html());
    })
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fontAwesome, to show some 'img'. For example, using &#xF046 can show a checkbox image. It's better than nothing.