# Add photos to html form

Tags: html, forms

Can I do something like this in html forms?

```
<select name="carlist" form="carform">
  <option value="volvo"><img src="volvo.png"></option>
  <option value="saab"><img src="saab.png"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: No.  `select` elements don't work that way.  There are JavaScript libraries and plugins which will allow you to create richer elements which populate a hidden `select` element, I'm sure.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images