# Adding image to bootstrap select?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 7x7px image i want to add next to each select option for my page.
Do i need to add the image in the CSS or can i add it in the HTML? I would like the image to the left side of the text also. I tried adding a image also but that just messes up the style.
Thanks for the help!

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Red</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Green</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Image Droprdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.thisisanfield.com/images/flat_web_icon_set/color/Facebook.png" width="17px" />Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.atmospherehotelsandresorts.com/images/icon-twitter.png" width="17px" />Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thincons/100/menu-128.png" width="17px" />List Image</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternative :

```js
var shownnn = "yes";
var dropd = document.getElementById("image-dropdown");

function showww() {
  dropd.style.height = "auto";
  dropd.style.overflow = "y-scroll";
}

function hideee() {
    dropd.style.height = "30px";
    dropd.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
  //dropd.addEventListener('mouseover', showOrHide, false);
  //dropd.addEventListener('click',showOrHide , false);


function myfuunc(imgParent) {
  hideee();
  var mainDIVV = document.getElementById("image-dropdown");
  imgParent.parentNode.removeChild(imgParent);
  mainDIVV.insertBefore(imgParent, mainDIVV.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```css
#image-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#image-dropdown {
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/*#image-dropdown:hover {} */

#image-dropdown .img_holder {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#image-dropdown img.flagimgs {
  height: 30px;
}
#image-dropdown span.iTEXT {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}
```

```html
<!-- not tested in mobiles -->

<div id="image-dropdown" onmouseleave="hideee();">
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs first" src="http://www.google.com/tv/images/socialyoutube.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">First</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thincons/100/menu-128.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Second</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="http://www.google.com/tv/images/lplay.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Third</span>
  </div>
  <div class="img_holder" onclick="myfuunc(this);" onmouseover="showww();">
    <img class="flagimgs second" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/thincons/100/menu-128.png" /> <span class="iTEXT">Fourth</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714400/2142994)