# Display drop down with images in select tag using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to display a drop down with images and text.
similar to this http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags but using javascript

I have a restriction to use only javascript to solve this.

I tried using the below code but it seems to work only in Mozilla

```
<select> 
  <option value="Country">Country</option>
  <option value="Germany" class="c_germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="USA" class="c_usa">USA</option>
</select>
<style> 
  .c_germany { background-image:url(download.png); } 
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Show code and effort. This is a FAQ with MANY examples here and elsewhere on the web

Comment: You can use same code which one you showing in http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags   it is working fine  just change the images path and content you want to display in dropdown.

Comment: It is a jQuery plugin - OP likely wants plain JS for some reason he did not bother to tell us - second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508029/dropdown-select-with-images

Comment: I have a restriction to use only javascript to solve this.I tried using the below code but it seems to work only in Mozilla                                  <select>
  <option value="Country">Country</option>
  <option value="Germany" class="c_germany">Germany</option>
  <option value="USA" class="c_usa">USA</option>
</select>                                                                                                                                                                                         <style>
.c_germany {
 background-image:url(download.png);
}
</style>

Comment: So solve it and show us your solution and ask specific questions if you have an issue. This is not elance.com. Also UPDATE your question instead of posting code in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    (function($) {
            $(function() {
                var isoCountries = [
                    { id: 'AF', text: 'Afghanistan'},
                    { id: 'AX', text: 'Aland Islands'},
                    { id: 'AL', text: 'Albania'},
                    { id: 'DZ', text: 'Algeria'},
                    { id: 'AS', text: 'American Samoa'},
                    { id: 'AD', text: 'Andorra'},
                    { id: 'AO', text: 'Angola'},
                    { id: 'AI', text: 'Anguilla'},
                    { id: 'AQ', text: 'Antarctica'},
                    { id: 'AG', text: 'Antigua And Barbuda'},
                    { id: 'AR', text: 'Argentina'},
                    { id: 'AM', text: 'Armenia'},
                    { id: 'AW', text: 'Aruba'},
                    { id: 'AU', text: 'Australia'},
                    { id: 'AT', text: 'Austria'},
                    { id: 'AZ', text: 'Azerbaijan'},
                    { id: 'BS', text: 'Bahamas'},
                    { id: 'BH', text: 'Bahrain'},
                    { id: 'BD', text: 'Bangladesh'},
                    { id: 'BB', text: 'Barbados'},
                    { id: 'BY', text: 'Belarus'},
                    { id: 'BE', text: 'Belgium'},
                    { id: 'BZ', text: 'Belize'},
                    { id: 'BJ', text: 'Benin'},
                    { id: 'BM', text: 'Bermuda'},
                    { id: 'BT', text: 'Bhutan'},
                    { id: 'BO', text: 'Bolivia'},
                    { id: 'BA', text: 'Bosnia And Herzegovina'},
                    { id: 'BW', text: 'Botswana'},
                    { id: 'BV', text: 'Bouvet Island'},
                    { id: 'BR', text: 'Brazil'},
                    { id: 'IO', text: 'British Indian Ocean Territory'},
                    { id: 'BN', text: 'Brunei Darussalam'},
                    { id: 'BG', text: 'Bulgaria'},
                    { id: 'BF', text: 'Burkina Faso'},
                    { id: 'BI', text: 'Burundi'},
                    { id: 'KH', text: 'Cambodia'},
                    { id: 'CM', text: 'Cameroon'},
                    { id: 'CA', text: 'Canada'},
                    { id: 'CV', text: 'Cape Verde'},
                    { id: 'KY', text: 'Cayman Islands'},
                    { id: 'CF', text: 'Central African Republic'},
                    { id: 'TD', text: 'Chad'},
                    { id: 'CL', text: 'Chile'},
                    { id: 'CN', text: 'China'},
                    { id: 'CX', text: 'Christmas Island'},
                    { id: 'CC', text: 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands'},
                    { id: 'CO', text: 'Colombia'},
                    { id: 'KM', text: 'Comoros'},
                    { id: 'CG', text: 'Congo'},
                    { id: 'CD', text: 'Congo}, Democratic Republic'},
                    { id: 'CK', text: 'Cook Islands'},
                    { id: 'CR', text: 'Costa Rica'},
                    { id: 'CI', text: 'Cote D\'Ivoire'},
                    { id: 'HR', text: 'Croatia'},
                    { id: 'CU', text: 'Cuba'},
                    { id: 'CY', text: 'Cyprus'},
                    { id: 'CZ', text: 'Czech Republic'},
                    { id: 'DK', text: 'Denmark'},
                    { id: 'DJ', text: 'Djibouti'},
                    { id: 'DM', text: 'Dominica'},
                    { id: 'DO', text: 'Dominican Republic'},
                    { id: 'EC', text: 'Ecuador'},
                    { id: 'EG', text: 'Egypt'},
                    { id: 'SV', text: 'El Salvador'},
                    { id: 'GQ', text: 'Equatorial Guinea'},
                    { id: 'ER', text: 'Eritrea'},
                    { id: 'EE', text: 'Estonia'},
                    { id: 'ET', text: 'Ethiopia'},
                    { id: 'FK', text: 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)'},
                    { id: 'FO', text: 'Faroe Islands'},
                    { id: 'FJ', text: 'Fiji'},
                    { id: 'FI', text: 'Finland'},
                    { id: 'FR', text: 'France'},
                    { id: 'GF', text: 'French Guiana'},
                    { id: 'PF', text: 'French Polynesia'},
                    { id: 'TF', text: 'French Southern Territories'},
                    { id: 'GA', text: 'Gabon'},
                    { id: 'GM', text: 'Gambia'},
                    { id: 'GE', text: 'Georgia'},
                    { id: 'DE', text: 'Germany'},
                    { id: 'GH', text: 'Ghana'},
                    { id: 'GI', text: 'Gibraltar'},
                    { id: 'GR', text: 'Greece'},
                    { id: 'GL', text: 'Greenland'},
                    { id: 'GD', text: 'Grenada'},
                    { id: 'GP', text: 'Guadeloupe'},
                    { id: 'GU', text: 'Guam'},
                    { id: 'GT', text: 'Guatemala'},
                    { id: 'GG', text: 'Guernsey'},
                    { id: 'GN', text: 'Guinea'},
                    { id: 'GW', text: 'Guinea-Bissau'},
                    { id: 'GY', text: 'Guyana'},
                    { id: 'HT', text: 'Haiti'},
                    { id: 'HM', text: 'Heard Island & Mcdonald Islands'},
                    { id: 'VA', text: 'Holy See (Vatican City State)'},
                    { id: 'HN', text: 'Honduras'},
                    { id: 'HK', text: 'Hong Kong'},
                    { id: 'HU', text: 'Hungary'},
                    { id: 'IS', text: 'Iceland'},
                    { id: 'IN', text: 'India'},
                    { id: 'ID', text: 'Indonesia'},
                    { id: 'IR', text: 'Iran}, Islamic Republic Of'},
                    { id: 'IQ', text: 'Iraq'},
                    { id: 'IE', text: 'Ireland'},
                    { id: 'IM', text: 'Isle Of Man'},
                    { id: 'IL', text: 'Israel'},
                    { id: 'IT', text: 'Italy'},
                    { id: 'JM', text: 'Jamaica'},
                    { id: 'JP', text: 'Japan'},
                    { id: 'JE', text: 'Jersey'},
                    { id: 'JO', text: 'Jordan'},
                    { id: 'KZ', text: 'Kazakhstan'},
                    { id: 'KE', text: 'Kenya'},
                    { id: 'KI', text: 'Kiribati'},
                    { id: 'KR', text: 'Korea'},
                    { id: 'KW', text: 'Kuwait'},
                    { id: 'KG', text: 'Kyrgyzstan'},
                    { id: 'LA', text: 'Lao People\'s Democratic Republic'},
                    { id: 'LV', text: 'Latvia'},
                    { id: 'LB', text: 'Lebanon'},
                    { id: 'LS', text: 'Lesotho'},
                    { id: 'LR', text: 'Liberia'},
                    { id: 'LY', text: 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya'},
                    { id: 'LI', text: 'Liechtenstein'},
                    { id: 'LT', text: 'Lithuania'},
                    { id: 'LU', text: 'Luxembourg'},
                    { id: 'MO', text: 'Macao'},
                    { id: 'MK', text: 'Macedonia'},
                    { id: 'MG', text: 'Madagascar'},
                    { id: 'MW', text: 'Malawi'},
                    { id: 'MY', text: 'Malaysia'},
                    { id: 'MV', text: 'Maldives'},
                    { id: 'ML', text: 'Mali'},
                    { id: 'MT', text: 'Malta'},
                    { id: 'MH', text: 'Marshall Islands'},
                    { id: 'MQ', text: 'Martinique'},
                    { id: 'MR', text: 'Mauritania'},
                    { id: 'MU', text: 'Mauritius'},
                    { id: 'YT', text: 'Mayotte'},
                    { id: 'MX', text: 'Mexico'},
                    { id: 'FM', text: 'Micronesia}, Federated States Of'},
                    { id: 'MD', text: 'Moldova'},
                    { id: 'MC', text: 'Monaco'},
                    { id: 'MN', text: 'Mongolia'},
                    { id: 'ME', text: 'Montenegro'},
                    { id: 'MS', text: 'Montserrat'},
                    { id: 'MA', text: 'Morocco'},
                    { id: 'MZ', text: 'Mozambique'},
                    { id: 'MM', text: 'Myanmar'},
                    { id: 'NA', text: 'Namibia'},
                    { id: 'NR', text: 'Nauru'},
                    { id: 'NP', text: 'Nepal'},
                    { id: 'NL', text: 'Netherlands'},
                    { id: 'AN', text: 'Netherlands Antilles'},
                    { id: 'NC', text: 'New Caledonia'},
                    { id: 'NZ', text: 'New Zealand'},
                    { id: 'NI', text: 'Nicaragua'},
                    { id: 'NE', text: 'Niger'},
                    { id: 'NG', text: 'Nigeria'},
                    { id: 'NU', text: 'Niue'},
                    { id: 'NF', text: 'Norfolk Island'},
                    { id: 'MP', text: 'Northern Mariana Islands'},
                    { id: 'NO', text: 'Norway'},
                    { id: 'OM', text: 'Oman'},
                    { id: 'PK', text: 'Pakistan'},
                    { id: 'PW', text: 'Palau'},
                    { id: 'PS', text: 'Palestinian Territory}, Occupied'},
                    { id: 'PA', text: 'Panama'},
                    { id: 'PG', text: 'Papua New Guinea'},
                    { id: 'PY', text: 'Paraguay'},
                    { id: 'PE', text: 'Peru'},
                    { id: 'PH', text: 'Philippines'},
                    { id: 'PN', text: 'Pitcairn'},
                    { id: 'PL', text: 'Poland'},
                    { id: 'PT', text: 'Portugal'},
                    { id: 'PR', text: 'Puerto Rico'},
                    { id: 'QA', text: 'Qatar'},
                    { id: 'RE', text: 'Reunion'},
                    { id: 'RO', text: 'Romania'},
                    { id: 'RU', text: 'Russian Federation'},
                    { id: 'RW', text: 'Rwanda'},
                    { id: 'BL', text: 'Saint Barthelemy'},
                    { id: 'SH', text: 'Saint Helena'},
                    { id: 'KN', text: 'Saint Kitts And Nevis'},
                    { id: 'LC', text: 'Saint Lucia'},
                    { id: 'MF', text: 'Saint Martin'},
                    { id: 'PM', text: 'Saint Pierre And Miquelon'},
                    { id: 'VC', text: 'Saint Vincent And Grenadines'},
                    { id: 'WS', text: 'Samoa'},
                    { id: 'SM', text: 'San Marino'},
                    { id: 'ST', text: 'Sao Tome And Principe'},
                    { id: 'SA', text: 'Saudi Arabia'},
                    { id: 'SN', text: 'Senegal'},
                    { id: 'RS', text: 'Serbia'},
                    { id: 'SC', text: 'Seychelles'},
                    { id: 'SL', text: 'Sierra Leone'},
                    { id: 'SG', text: 'Singapore'},
                    { id: 'SK', text: 'Slovakia'},
                    { id: 'SI', text: 'Slovenia'},
                    { id: 'SB', text: 'Solomon Islands'},
                    { id: 'SO', text: 'Somalia'},
                    { id: 'ZA', text: 'South Africa'},
                    { id: 'GS', text: 'South Georgia And Sandwich Isl.'},
                    { id: 'ES', text: 'Spain'},
                    { id: 'LK', text: 'Sri Lanka'},
                    { id: 'SD', text: 'Sudan'},
                    { id: 'SR', text: 'Suriname'},
                    { id: 'SJ', text: 'Svalbard And Jan Mayen'},
                    { id: 'SZ', text: 'Swaziland'},
                    { id: 'SE', text: 'Sweden'},
                    { id: 'CH', text: 'Switzerland'},
                    { id: 'SY', text: 'Syrian Arab Republic'},
                    { id: 'TW', text: 'Taiwan'},
                    { id: 'TJ', text: 'Tajikistan'},
                    { id: 'TZ', text: 'Tanzania'},
                    { id: 'TH', text: 'Thailand'},
                    { id: 'TL', text: 'Timor-Leste'},
                    { id: 'TG', text: 'Togo'},
                    { id: 'TK', text: 'Tokelau'},
                    { id: 'TO', text: 'Tonga'},
                    { id: 'TT', text: 'Trinidad And Tobago'},
                    { id: 'TN', text: 'Tunisia'},
                    { id: 'TR', text: 'Turkey'},
                    { id: 'TM', text: 'Turkmenistan'},
                    { id: 'TC', text: 'Turks And Caicos Islands'},
                    { id: 'TV', text: 'Tuvalu'},
                    { id: 'UG', text: 'Uganda'},
                    { id: 'UA', text: 'Ukraine'},
                    { id: 'AE', text: 'United Arab Emirates'},
                    { id: 'GB', text: 'United Kingdom'},
                    { id: 'US', text: 'United States'},
                    { id: 'UM', text: 'United States Outlying Islands'},
                    { id: 'UY', text: 'Uruguay'},
                    { id: 'UZ', text: 'Uzbekistan'},
                    { id: 'VU', text: 'Vanuatu'},
                    { id: 'VE', text: 'Venezuela'},
                    { id: 'VN', text: 'Viet Nam'},
                    { id: 'VG', text: 'Virgin Islands}, British'},
                    { id: 'VI', text: 'Virgin Islands}, U.S.'},
                    { id: 'WF', text: 'Wallis And Futuna'},
                    { id: 'EH', text: 'Western Sahara'},
                    { id: 'YE', text: 'Yemen'},
                    { id: 'ZM', text: 'Zambia'},
                    { id: 'ZW', text: 'Zimbabwe'}
                ];

                function formatCountry (country) {
                  if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
                  var $country = $(
                    '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-'+ country.id.toLowerCase() +' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
                    '<span class="flag-text">'+ country.text+"</span>"
                  );
                  return $country;
                };

                //Assuming you have a select element with name country
                // e.g. <select name="name"></select>

                $("[name='country']").select2({
                    placeholder: "Select a country",
                    templateResult: formatCountry,
                    data: isoCountries
                });


            });
    })(jQuery);
<script>
```

https://codepen.io/abhishek/pen/bkfLi

Comment: Where is the plain JS here? Also where is this code from? Please add credit - I found one here: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/sgb4888k/2/

Comment: Add the link to your answer

Comment: Thank Raj Kumar for the links that you mentioned but all those solutions are in jQuery and not javascript

Comment: let me create my own