# Dropdown with checkbox hack - how to make first tap open menu without selecting option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want to make something that is like a dropdown  menu in a form, but I want to be able to show images or other content in each option. A bit like [msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) but with the ability to put any content in the dropdown, not just images. For instance, I might want coloured rectangles that are inline-block elements styled with css.

The way I'm approaching it at the moment is by building on this [checkbox hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599581/3093080)

Here's what I've got so far, which works well in the desktop browsers that I've tested:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL7jq8nq/3/)

The trouble is that on iOS and Android, when you click on the dropdown to expand it, it selects the first option in the list. I want that first click to expand the dropdown, but not to click any options yet. Is there a way to do this, e.g. by adding a simple bit of javascript?

Or, alternatively, is there a more elegant way to go about solving the whole problem of putting arbitrary content in a dropdown instead of using the checkbox hack?

Full code from JSfiddle below:

HTML

```
<p>Show what's currently selected, using javascript:</p>

<input type="text" value="" id="trace"/>

<p>Dropdown with custom styling, using the checkbox hack, along the lines of <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/9599581/3093080">this</a>, using the variant suggested by "namehere" in the comments.</p>

<form class="my-image-dropdown">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="line-style" value="1"  />
        <div class="dropdown-label">
            <span class="color-swatch vmiddle">
                <span style="background-color:red;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:green;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:blue;">&nbsp;</span>    
            </span>
            <span class="collapsedonly vmiddle">&#9662;</span>
            <span class="checkedonly vmiddle">&#x2713;</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="line-style" value="2" checked="checked"/>
        <div class="dropdown-label">
            <span class="color-swatch vmiddle">
                <span style="background-color:purple;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:green;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:pink;">&nbsp;</span>    
            </span>
            <span class="collapsedonly vmiddle">&#9662;</span>
            <span class="checkedonly vmiddle">&#x2713;</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="line-style" value="3" />
        <div class="dropdown-label">
            <span class="color-swatch vmiddle">
                <span style="background-color:grey;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:darkblue;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:black;">&nbsp;</span>    
            </span>
            <span class="collapsedonly vmiddle">&#9662;</span>
            <span class="checkedonly vmiddle">&#x2713;</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="line-style" value="4" />
        <div class="dropdown-label">
            <span class="color-swatch vmiddle">
                <span style="background-color:yellow;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:orange;">&nbsp;</span><span style="background-color:green;">&nbsp;</span>    
            </span>
            <span class="collapsedonly vmiddle">&#9662;</span>
            <span class="checkedonly vmiddle">&#x2713;</span>
        </div>
    </label>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/* Update the trace showing currently selected option */
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function(){$("#trace").val($("input:checked").val());},100);
});

/* Fix the sticky hover bug on iOS - see http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/    entry.php?335-iOS-Sticky-Hover-Fix-Unhovering-dropdown-CSS-menus */
(function(l){var i,s={touchend:function(){}};for(i in s)l.addEventListener(i,s)})(document);
```

CSS

```
/* Hide the radio buttons */
.my-image-dropdown input {
    /*height: 0; width: 0; opacity:0;*/ /* This was in original code, seems unnecessary */
    display:none; /* Using display:none seems easier than setting height, width, opacity */
}


/* Style the container for both minimized and maximised state*/
.my-image-dropdown {
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    background: #DDDDDD;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}


/* Collapse the dropdown when no hover, by hiding the contents of the label elements */
.my-image-dropdown label input ~ * {
    display:none;  
}


/* Expand the dropdown on hover (mouse) or tap (touch-screen) */
.my-image-dropdown:hover {
    height: auto;  /* Use fixed height or else auto to fit all color swatches */
    overflow-y: scroll;  /* If fixed height, use native scrolling */
}
.my-image-dropdown:hover label input ~ * {
    /* Use display:inline-block for tiling           */                             
    /*   or display:block;       for full-width vertical stacking */
    /*   or display:table;       for vertical stacking and fit to width of contents */
    display: table;  /* Vertical stacking and fit to width of contents */
}

/* Add some space between rows when expanded */
/* This uses the :not() selector which has pretty solid browser support */
/* http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3 */
.my-image-dropdown:hover label:not(:first-child) input ~ * {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Display the checked option even when the dropdown is collapsed */
.my-image-dropdown label input:checked ~ * {
    display:table;
    /* Optional: apply styling to the chosen option */
}

/* Apply effect when hovering over a particular label */
.my-image-dropdown label:hover input ~ * {
    opacity:0.5;
}

/* Show the down arrow only when collapsed and only for the checked option */
.my-image-dropdown label .collapsedonly {
    display:none;
}
.my-image-dropdown label input:checked ~ .dropdown-label .collapsedonly {
    display:inline;
}
.my-image-dropdown:hover label input:checked ~ .dropdown-label .collapsedonly {
    display:none;
}


/* Show a tick next to the checked option but only when expanded */
.my-image-dropdown label .checkedonly {
    display:none;
}
.my-image-dropdown:hover label input:checked ~ .dropdown-label .checkedonly {
    display:inline;
}


/* Style the tick and the down arrow */
.dropdown-label .checkedonly, .dropdown-label .collapsedonly {
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


/* Style the colored squares */
.color-swatch{
    display: inline-block;
}
.color-swatch > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px; /* If you change this then also change line-height of dropdown-label */
    margin:2px;
}

/* Vertically center an element within its neighbour */
.vmiddle {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On reflection, it's easier just to code a dropdown from scratch using jquery instead of trying to fix the checkbox hack. The best solution I found was this: 
http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/